# Optimising Functions Working Through A Long String

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a very long string in javascript which needs to be worked on by many functions in javascript.

Call the string:

```
 var str;
```

The successive functions start where the last function left off. So I keep a variable `strPos` to indicate where I am along the string.

Each function returns the new position along the string, ie

```
function MyStringFunction(str, strPos){
    /* Does some fantastic work on the str without changing it */

    /* Say this function move strPos on 10 characters so we return */
    return (10 + strPos);
}
```

Is that the optimal FASTEST way of doing things?

Should I reduce the string instead?

```
// NOW RETURNS THE SHORTENED STRING MINUS THE STUFF I HAVE NOW WORKED ON
// strPos is now always the start of the string, as that is now where I left off
function MyStringFunction(str){
    /* Does some fantastic work on the str without changing it */

    /* Say this function works on 10 characters so we return */
    return str.substr(10);
}
```

Which is the FASTEST way of doing it? Please note the string starts out about 20 thousand characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course performance will depend from js engine implementation and possible optimizations introduced by it. But theoretically string traversal via the index based approach will be more performant. The point is that the string in JS *is an index based immutable list of unsigned 16 bit integers.* From that I make two simple conclusions:

1. Index-based part means that it's guaranteed that we have O(1)
   complexity upon access to any element of the string;
2. Immutable part means that even if one managed to build all the calculation-flow as a chain
   of function calls that would still require wasting some computational
   time to create substrings during each call. So that makes no much sense to me.

Here I made some very basic benchmarking. Of course it's nothing compared to a serious test but still does the thing:

```
const INIT = {
  str: 'x'.repeat(10e6),
  i: 0,
  startTime: 0,
};

let t = {};

const setup = () => {
  t = { ...INIT, startTime: Date.now() };
}

const fooIndexApproach = (str, idx) => {
  const upto = idx + 10;
  for (let i = idx; i < upto; i++) str.charCodeAt(i);
  return upto;
}
const fooSubStrApproach = (str) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) str.charCodeAt(i);
  return str.slice(10);
}


// the first run-by is not taken into account as 'warmed-up' engine optimizations
// may affect the performance 
setup();
for (let j = 0; j < 10e3; j++);
while ((t.i = fooIndexApproach(t.str, t.i)) < t.str.length) { };

setup();
for (let j = 0; j < 10e3; j++);
while ((t.i = fooIndexApproach(t.str, t.i)) < t.str.length) { };
console.log(`fooIndexApproach: ${(Date.now() - t.startTime)}ms`);


// the first run-by is not taken into account as 'warmed-up' engine optimizations
// may affect the performance 
setup();
for (let j = 0; j < 10e3; j++);
while (t.str = fooSubStrApproach(t.str)) { };

setup();
for (let j = 0; j < 10e3; j++);
while (t.str = fooSubStrApproach(t.str)) { };
console.log(`fooSubStrApproach: ${(Date.now() - t.startTime)}ms`);

// ==============================================
// RESULTS on my Mac:
// substring VS indexed => [[51, 19], [51, 20]]ms
// indexed VS substring => [[31, 52], [32, 52]]ms
```

Quite self explanatory numbers, I must say. Indexed approach wins which is not surprising though.